# Javascript Date Object gives different timezones for differently formatted date strings

Tags: javascript, datetime

Does anyone know why the Javascript Date object changes the timezone based on how your string is formatted and if there is a way to avoid it?

For example, on the West coast (Firefox uses PST for some reason, Chrome uses  PDT),

```
new Date("08/30/2018") -> Date 2018-08-30T08:00:00.000Z
```

while

```
new Date("2018-08-30") -> Date 2018-08-30T00:00:00.000Z
```

It took me a while to debug this issue, and I would rather not have to add extra code, if possible, for changing the timezone or reformatting the input string.

Comment: First one is not a valid ISO string format and second is technically incomplete ISO. Some browsers will parse first one as invalid date. Break the string down into it's components and pass those as arguments in new Date and will get consistent results

Comment: Every browser I've used (Firefox, Chrome, IE, Edge) does the same thing, so I'm just wondering why.  Every browser defaults invalid strings to local time, while semi-valid defaults to GMT?

Comment: I did run first one in firefox just now and was surprised it didn't return invalid date. It would have a year ago or so...they must have changed their internal date parser. It used to be that chrome would accept some non standard formats and output a date when firefox wouldn't. Irregardless...never safe to use non standard formats and is always safer to pass to arguments as `new Date(y,m,d...)` for consistent cross browser support

Comment: @DanielH Found the answer from the docs, posted below.

Comment: @ Jason The issue came up comparing values created from differently formatted strings.  It's just annoying, but thanks for the spec reference... not sure why I didn't find that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an answer from the spec, but I can guess. @charlietfl is on the right track - `08/30/2018` is a US (or otherwise "local") specific format - it's not internationally recognized, and in particular most European countries reverse the order of the day and month.  So, if you're putting the time in a local format, it assumes you don't know any better and just sets the timezone to whatever the system timezone is in the browser.

If you use the normalized string that *is* internationally recognized, then it doesn't assume what timezone you mean when you enter it, it just sets it to UTC.  If you want to specify your server timezone, or the timezone of the user, you'll have to specify that.

I recommend, if the timezone is important, that you specify it when you initialize the object (even if you *want* UTC) because it's always better to reduce ambiguity.  In particular, in this case, *your* browser is using Pacific time, because, presumably, you're on the West Coast.  Mine is using Eastern, because I'm on the East Coast, so the timestamp is different for the first case - it's using *my* local time.  The internationally recognized date format is UTC for both of us.

EDIT:

I wasn't satisfied with guessing. [According to the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), `Date()` uses the `Date.parse()` method to parse the string and recognize which date is wanted - ostensibly it follows the specs [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) and [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) - those appear to be only minimally helpful here, without spending more time than I'm willing.

[Documentation for `Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) indicates that it takes the input value and returns milliseconds since the Epoch.

Here's the relevant bit for you, from `Date.parse()`:

> Given a date string of "March 7, 2014", parse() assumes a local time zone, but given an ISO format such as "2014-03-07" it will assume a time zone of UTC

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the docs for Date on mozilla

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

> Note: parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and
>   Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to
>   browser differences and inconsistencies. Support for RFC 2822 format
>   strings is by convention only. Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in
>   that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not
>   local.

I'd recommend using https://momentjs.com/ or even https://moment.github.io/luxon/ for date parsing using a combo of `datestring + format`

```
moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! @Jason answered a minute before you so I accepted his answer.  I appreciate the help!  I'll consider using moment, but since it's just one specific case for me, it may be faster to code the conversion myself.